# A question about commutator in a group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that the group $G$ has a series of normal subgroups $G\geq D\geq Z(G)$. Let $D/Z=‎\prod‎_{‎\lambda ‎\in I‎}C_{‎\lambda‎}/Z$. How can I get $[G,D]=\langle [G,C_{\lambda}]\; |\; \lambda \in I\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quotienting out $\langle [G,C_\lambda] \mid \lambda \in I \rangle$, it is enough to show that if all elements of $G$ commute with all $C_\lambda$, then $[G,D]=1$.

But $D$ is generated by the $C_\lambda$ and $Z(G)$, so this follows.